# Select double digit pane in tmux

Tags: session, terminal, tmux

I have 12 panes in a tmux session. I created them by clicking `ctrl` + `b`

I know how to access panes 0-9. I clicked `ctrl` + `[0-9]`

How do I access panes 10 or above? It automatically switches panes after I click the first number.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean windows or panes? If windows you can access higher numbers by doing `C-b '` then typing the number, or by using tree mode with `C-b w`. Or you can turn the mouse on (`set -g mouse on`) then click on the window name on the status line. Or by using `C-b n` and `C-b p` to move forward and back between windows.

If panes, then you can navigate with `C-b` then the arrow keys or turn the mouse on then click on the pane.

Comment: Great I'll type in `cntrl-b set -g mouse on`

Comment: Wow, that worked and it's so good. Can I also allow for scrolling?

Comment: What do you mean scrolling?